# Download file throught PHP without storing it first

Tags: php

I have a server `Server1` which is a Windows based server and can connect to a Domain Controller. `Server1` has a Web Application which receives a username and password to authenticate and download a file.

My main application resides in `Server2` which is a Linux baser server. The main application has an API which receives a file name, pass it to `Server1` with some extra credentials and downloads a file.

What I want to do is instead of downloading the file first in `Server2` then pushing it to the client, I want to let `Server2` push the file to the client directly ??

Comment: Can the user access `Server2`?  You could have `Server1` issue a redirect to the user to send them to the specific URL on `Server2` which serves the file.

Comment: The main application is on `Server2`, i.e. `Server2` is the server which the user will access. `Server1` can only be accessed via `Server2`.

Comment: Ah, I got the two mixed up.  Swap them in my comment then :)  If the user can access `Server1` then when `Server2` responds to the user request it can respond with a redirect to the URL of the file on `Server1`, allowing the user to fetch it directly.  If the user can't access `Server1` and *must* go through `Server2` then `Server2` does need to first fetch the file and then send it to the user.  It doesn't need to save it to the file system, though.  It can just fetch the byte stream and then return that to the user.

Comment: but even if `Server2` fetched the file from `Server1` and storing it in a byte stream, doesn't that mean that `Server2` will waste time to downloaded it first, then sending it back to the user ??

Comment: Indeed it does.  But if the user can't access `Server1` then the user can't get the file directly.  Perhaps `Server2` can get direct access to the file system (or network share) so it doesn't need to get the file from `Server1` first?  It's probably worth measuring the speed difference between the two scenarios, it might not be enough to worry about.

Comment: The reason I used `Server1` because `Server2` cannot access the `Domain Controller` files. What I was thinking of, something like a tube application, that passes the stream directly to the user.

Comment: It may be possible to use PHP's stream functions to begin writing the response to the client before the full response is received from the private server.  Sounds kind of unreliable, though.  Are the files large enough that it really makes a difference?  That too is worth measuring before spending a lot of time and effort on a solution that may be more complex and more fragile than necessary.

Comment: So whats the problem?